# ExifLib requires a seekable stream

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, exif, bitmapimage, exiflib

I am getting an error while instantiating ExifReader in Windows Phone 8 C#. Please find the code snippet below. Kindly do the needful

Error : "ExifLib requires a seekable stream"

```
byte[] imageBytes = (byte[])PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ViewImage"];

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes,0,imageBytes.Length);

BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

bitmapImage.SetSource(ms);

try
{
    ExifReader xif = new ExifReader(toStream(bitmapImage)); // Getting Error here
    double gpsLat, gpsLng;
    xif.GetTagValue<double>(ExifTags.GPSLatitude, out gpsLat);
    xif.GetTagValue<double>(ExifTags.GPSLongitude, out gpsLng);

    map.Center = new System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate(gpsLat, gpsLng);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
}

Stream toStream(BitmapImage img)
{
    WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapSource)img);
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bmp.SaveJpeg(stream, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `MemoryStream` is returning false when [`CanSeek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canseek.aspx) is called. This is because you've wrapped your `MemoryStream` in a `using` statement, which means that you're returning a disposed object.

Your `toStream` method should actually look like this:

```
Stream ToStream(BitmapImage img)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    using (WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapSource)img))
    {
        bmp.SaveJpeg(stream, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
    }
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: No worries. Thinking about it some more, you should actually put `bmp` into a `using` statement, however, as all GDI+ objects use unmanaged resources. I've edited my answer to show this change.